# How to revert back the page settings to default settings using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, django, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an html page which has several angularJS components with several settings. Am planning to implement a Cancel button below so that once the user clicks on the button the whole settings are cleared and revert to original state. Am using Django framework here. How can I do that using angularJS? Thanks in advance.

Following is my codes:

Html:

```
    <table class="table">

        {% verbatim %}

        <tr>

            <td class="input-group" ng-repeat="(k,v) in alerts">

                <span class="input-group-addon" ng-hide="v.hide">Check {{ k }}</span>
                <span ng-hide="v.hide">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Add Check here" ng-model="v.input">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <b>Functional check</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="{{ k }}" value="fc" ng-model="v.props">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <b>CFM issue</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="{{ k }}" value="cfm" ng-model="v.props">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <b>Defect risk</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="{{ k }}" value="dr" ng-model="v.props">

            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a href="" ng-click="remove(v)">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
                    </span>
                    <!--<a href="" ng-click="remove(v)">remove</a></span></td>  </tr>-->
        {% endverbatim %}
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class='btn btn-info' ng-click="addAlert()">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                    &nbsp;Add Check</button>
            <button type="reset" ng-click="reset()" class="btn btn-danger">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></span>
                &nbsp;Reset</button>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<table class="table">
    <!--IMPORT FILE-->

    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="position:relative;">
                <a class='btn btn-primary' href='javascript:;'>
                    Choose File...
                    <input type="file" style='position:absolute;z-index:2;top:0;left:0;
                    filter: alpha(opacity=0);-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
                    opacity:0;background-color:transparent;color:transparent;' name="file_source" size="40"  onchange='$("#upload-file-info").html($(this).val());'>
                </a>
                &nbsp;
                <span class='label label-info' id="upload-file-info"></span>
                <button ng-click="uploadAttachFile()" class="btn btn-small btn-default" id="uploadfile" name="uploadfile">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></span>&nbsp;Import File</button>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <!--ADD COMMENTS-->

    <tr>
        <td>
            Add Comments*<h4><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Comments here">
        </h4>

        </td>
        <td>
            Add xx<h4><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Add xx here">
        </h4>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-small btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>&nbsp;Update check DB</button>
            <button class="btn btn-small btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>&nbsp;Cancel</button>
        </td>
</table>
```

and my JS:

```
{{ ngapp }}.controller("AlertDemoCtrl", function ($scope, $http){

$scope.alerts = [];

$scope.addAlert = function() {
$scope.alerts.push({msg: 'Another alert!', props : 0, input : ""});
};

$scope.closeAlert = function(index) {
$scope.alerts.splice(index, 1);
};

$scope.reset = function() {
angular.forEach($scope.alerts, function(v){
v.input = "";
v.props = 0;
});
};

$scope.remove = function(v){
    v.hide = 1;
  }

$scope.reset();
});
```

Comment: Your description is a bit vague - could you perhaps provide what code you have already, and we can work from there?

Comment: What do you mean by components? Settings? You could have a cancel button that sets all your scope models to some default values, which would also update your views.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question - but here is how i interpret it:

You have a cancel button. Add an ng-click attribute that calls a function in your respective controller. In that function, simply initialize all of your "settings" (which should be $scope objects). This should accomplish what you are describing.

Comment: Yeah. Actually, the settings might be distributed amongst different scopes, so it might be a good idea to use `$rootScope.$broadcast` when the Cancel button is clicked so all the relevant scopes could listen for it and do stuff. But the question is too unclear as it is now and needs to be clarified before we could actually answer it. Also, something feels off about this. I get the sense that it could/should be designed more modularly.

Comment: I agree. Depending on the tasks of the project OP, you may consider reading the documentation on Angular Services (i.e. 'SettingsService')